# NullPointerException when using GWT's AutoBean deserialization with HashMap

Tags: gwt, serialization, hashmap, nullpointerexception, autobean

I have some problem with the Google's AutoBean serialization and deserialization.
I have an AutoBean that contains primitive types and Maps as well. I can serialize and deserialize the primitive types without any problem, but when i try to read the deserialized  Map, i get NullPointerException.
Have you ever met with a similar problem before? There is a JUnit test that representes my problem. The first two asserts are passes, but the third fails.

```
public class AutoBeanTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        MyFactory myFactory = AutoBeanFactorySource.create(MyFactory.class);

        Options options = myFactory.options().as();
        options.setMyInt(5);
        HashMap<Double, Boolean> map = newHashMap();
        map.put(8.0, true);
        map.put(9.1, false);

        options.setMyMap(map);

        Options deserialized = AutoBeanCodex.decode(myFactory, Options.class, AutoBeanCodex.encode(AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(options)).getPayload()).as();
        assertEquals(deserialized.getMyInt(),5);
        assertTrue(options.getMyMap().containsKey(8d));
        assertTrue(deserialized.getMyMap().containsKey(8d));
    }

    public interface MyFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
        AutoBean<Options> options();
    }

    public interface Options {

        public int getMyInt();

        void setMyInt(int myInt);

        Map<Double, Boolean> getMyMap();

        void setMyMap(Map<Double, Boolean> myMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: `com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanCodexTest` checks out a lot of the map features include put/get across encode/decode - my guess would be that something is wonky with using doubles as keys, after encoding/decoding already imprecise values. Haven't tried running your test yet though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been playing around with the AutoBean functionality a while ago. I think it is still kind a buggy. I'm quite sure the exceptions is caused by a bug in the AutoBean code, not in your code.

If you run the above sample code in a debugger and check the generated JSON, things look fine. You can even call `deserialized.getMyMap().size()` and get the correct value, but once you want to access the content errors occur.

There is a workaround, just use `Map<String, String>` instead of `Double` or `Boolean` and it works...

Answer (score 1):

Ackchyually... Autobeans is doing it correctly as [in JSON only strings are allowed as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758715/using-number-as-index-json). But of course the error message should be more helpful.