# Newtonsoft.Json Ignores TypeConverters and/or JsonConverters, regardless of how it they're referenced

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an enum, for example:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyJSONConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    a,
    b,
    c
}
```

I have put the `JsonConverter` attribute on it.

I have defined the converter class:

```
public class MyJSONConverter : JsonConverter<MyEnum>
{
    public MyJSONConverter()
    {
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, MyEnum value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override MyEnum ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, MyEnum existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.Value)
        {
            case "a":
                return MyEnum.a;
            case "b":
                return MyEnum.b;
            case "c":
                return MyEnum.c;
        }

        return serializer.Deserialize<MyEnum>(reader);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Breakpoints dictate the class is being instantiated.  But it never calls any of the member methods or properties.

To my knowledge, that's all it should take to work.  It does not work.

I have tried TypeConverter and other classes that inherit JsonConverter, including the one without a generic argument, and the StringEnumConverter.  None of them work.

Although seemingly not necessary in any examples I have read, I have tried adding it as a converter to my settings:

```
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
        settings.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;
        settings.ContractResolver = new CShouldSerializeContractResolver();
        settings.Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new MyJSONConverter() };

        JsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
```

If I manually add it to my converters, the converter class gets instantiated once, upon instantiating the JsonSerializer itself, and upon attempting to deserialize.  It seems to never use any instances that are created.

The error clearly states to attempt to use a TypeConverter, but none of them work.

```
Could not convert string 'blahblah' to dictionary key type 'MyEnum'. 
Create a TypeConverter to convert from the string to the key type object. Path 
'Array[0].Keys.blahblah', line 1, position 1388.
```

Complete fiddle here, with exception occurring: https://dotnetfiddle.net/itCbER

Why doesn't Newtonsoft use any of the documented methods of converting?

Comment: Can you perhaps add breakpoints to the start of both WriteJson & ReadJson and see if it hits it first?

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem with a [mcve]?  Your code is incomplete and doesn't fully compile.  My best effort to get it to work is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cwSm6E.  I see the following problems: 1) you return `false` from `CanWrite` so the converter is not actually used during serialization.  2) During deserialization, if the JSON value isn't `"a"`, `"b"` or `"c"` you have an stack overflow because you attempt to deserialize the current JSON value using the incoming serializer -- which calls the converter recursively.

Comment: See e.g. [JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using `[JsonConvert()]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719509/3744182) for how to deal with such a stack overflow.

Comment: @EfthymiosKalyviotis As stated in the question, the only method/property to be called within the class is the constructor.  None of the others are called, ever.

Comment: @dbc CanWrite is never called, mysteriously.  The ReadJson method is also never called, so I never ran into any stack overflows.

Comment: @dbc I have altered your example to be closer to reality, and it does have the same error as I experience locally: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YzKcSA

Comment: Note that a `TypeConverter` is not a `JsonConverter`.  If you are using an enum for a **dictionary key** the `JsonConverter` for the key type is not invoked, see [json.net: specify converter for dictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6845364/3744182).

Comment: The log from the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/7SdBym proves that only the constructor is called in the converter.

Comment: Is this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/7SdBym not the minimum reproducible example?

Comment: Also, if you really are using `MyEnum` as a dictionary key and just want the enum names to be used as dictionary keys, then you don't need to do anything, it happens automatically.  See: [JSON.Net serializing Enums to strings in dictionaries by default - how to make it serialize to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25201242/3744182).

Comment: If you take a look at the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/itCbER, the goal is that I have old keys that no longer exist to be hotswapped with the new keys.

Comment: Right then.  It turns out that a `JsonConverter` is not used for **dictionary keys**.  See [json.net: specify converter for dictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6845364/3744182).

Comment: Also see [the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Dictionarys) which states, *When serializing a dictionary, the keys of the dictionary are converted to strings and used as the JSON object property names. The string written for a key can be customized by either overriding ToString() for the key type or by implementing a TypeConverter. A TypeConverter will also support converting a custom string back again when deserializing a dictionary.*  So the restriction is documented, albeit obscurely.

Comment: Is your real need to customize the names used for the `MyEnum` values when serialized to JSON?  Because you can do that simply by applying [`EnumMemberAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=netcore-3.1) to your enum values, see [How to make JSON.NET StringEnumConverter use hyphen-separated casing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22908204/3744182).  Unlike a custom `JsonConverter` that should work for dictionary keys, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/JWKDPb

Comment: @dbc The issue with EnumMemberAttribute is that I need to read incorrect strings, and convert them to the new enum value.  Whereas that simply replaces whenever it would read or write a specific enum with another string.

Comment: I need to replace from "some old string," whose enum value no longer exists, to a new enum value.

Comment: Is this acceptable: `public enum MyEnum { a, b, c, SomeOldNameOfB = b }`

Comment: @BenVoigt Unfortunately not in this situation, because we do iterate through the enum's values elsewhere in the project.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is making a special dictionary converter, feels like a nuclear option.  Something like this, but perhaps more optimized: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7010231/2589506

Comment: If I understand you, I think I've done something like this with a TypeSafeEnum 'pattern' and custom JsonConverter converter for the TypeSafeEnum, I'll try to get a minute and post an example to see if it fits your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a TypeSafeEnum with JsonConverter to control how values are transposed between my code and an external vendor API.

First, we setup our abstract `TypeSafeEnumBase` class that will be used by multiple objects.

```
// define a base class for our type safe enum
public abstract class TypeSafeEnumBase
{
    // the types for Name and Value could be different if needed...
    protected readonly string Name;  // would be string value on typical enum
    protected readonly int Value; // would be int value on typical enum

    protected TypeSafeEnumBase(int value, string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Next, we implement our `TypeSafeEnum`s that will inherit from the base enum. I've implemented two in this example, A class for `MyEnum` from your example and `MemberLanguage`, both inherit from the `TypeSafeEnumBase`. There is no actual `enum` being used, e.g. `public enum MyEnum {}`. I've added `MemberLanguage` to help show the benefit of the `TypeSafeEnumConversion` class that's used in the next step.

```
// define TypeSafeEnumBase that's a sealed class and inherits from the TypeSafeEnumBase
public sealed class MyEnum : TypeSafeEnumBase
{        
    // define 'enums'
    public static readonly MyEnum a = new MyEnum(1, "a");
    public static readonly MyEnum b = new MyEnum(2, "b");
    public static readonly MyEnum c = new MyEnum(3, "c");
    // add additional 'enums'...

    private MyEnum(int value, string name) :
        base(value, name)
    {
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MyEnum> MyEnums()
    {
        // this method only needed if you have to iterate over enums
        // and will need to be maintained as new MyEnums are added
        yield return a;
        yield return b;
        yield return c;
    }

    public static bool TryParse(int value, out MyEnum language)
    {
        return TryParse(value.ToString(), out language);
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string value, out MyEnum language)
    {
        try
        {
            language = Parse(value);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            language = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static MyEnum Parse(int value)
    {
        return Parse(value.ToString());
    }

    public static MyEnum Parse(string value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case nameof(a):
            case "1":
                return MyEnum.a;
            case nameof(b):
            case "2":
                return MyEnum.b;
            case nameof(c):
            case "3":
                return MyEnum.c;
            default:
                return null;
                // throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), $"Unable to parse for value, '{value}'. Not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public sealed class MemberLanguage : TypeSafeEnumBase
{
    // define 'enums'
    public static readonly MemberLanguage English = new MemberLanguage(1, "English");
    public static readonly MemberLanguage Spanish = new MemberLanguage(2, "Spanish");
    // add additional language types...
    // public static readonly MemberLanguage Farsi = new MemberLanguage(3, "Farsi");
    // etc...

    private MemberLanguage(int value, string name) :
        base(value, name)
    {
    }

    public static bool TryParse(int value, out MemberLanguage language)
    {
        return TryParse(value.ToString(), out language);
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string value, out MemberLanguage language)
    {
        try
        {
            language = Parse(value);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            language = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static MemberLanguage Parse(int value)
    {
        return Parse(value.ToString());
    }

    public static MemberLanguage Parse(string value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case nameof(English):
            case "ENG":
            case "1":
                return MemberLanguage.English;
            case nameof(Spanish):
            case "SPN":
            case "2":
                return MemberLanguage.Spanish;
            default:
                return null;
                // throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), $"Unable to parse for value, '{value}'. Not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Next, we create a conversion helper for our `TypeSafeEnum`s.
By creating this helper we can ensure our `JsonConverter` will not need to change should we add additional type safe enums. Should we add more, this class will get updated but the `JsonConverter` will not need to be updated.

```
public class TypeSafeEnumConversion
{
    public static object ConvertToTypeSafeEnum(string name, string value)
    {
        object returnValue = null;
        switch (name)
        {
            case nameof(MemberLanguage):
            returnValue = MemberLanguage.Parse(value);
            break;
            case nameof(MyEnum):
            returnValue = MyEnum.Parse(value);
            break;
            //case nameof(SomeOtherEnum):
            // returnValue = SomeOtherEnum.Parse(value);
            // break;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Now we create our custom `TypeSafeEnumJsonConverter` class that implements the `JsonConverter` object, and will call our conversion helper object. Again, this allows us to keep this converter object isolated, and prevents the need for changes to it should we add additional type safe enum objects

```
public class TypeSafeEnumJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{        
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        var types = new[] { typeof(TypeSafeEnumBase) };
        return types.Any(t => t == objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string name = objectType.Name;
        string value = serializer.Deserialize(reader).ToString();
        // call our custom conversion object
        return TypeSafeEnumConversion.ConvertToTypeSafeEnum(name, value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null
            && serializer.NullValueHandling == NullValueHandling.Ignore)
        {
            return;
        }
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString()); 
    }
}
```

How it's used...

Create an object that uses our `TypeSafeEnum`s.

```
public class SomeThing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("my_enum")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeSafeEnumJsonConverter))]
    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("language_preference")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeSafeEnumJsonConverter))]
    public MemberLanguage LanguagePreference { get; set; }  

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(SomeThing)} : {MyEnum} : {LanguagePreference}";
    }    
}
```

Usage...

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<string> jsonDatas = new List<string>();
        // Serialize
        foreach (MyEnum e in MyEnum.MyEnums())
        {
            var thing = new SomeThing();
            thing.Name = e.ToString().ToUpper();
            thing.LanguagePreference = MemberLanguage.English;
            thing.MyEnum = e;
            string o = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing);
            jsonDatas.Add(o);
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        }
        // Deserialize
        foreach (string json in jsonDatas)
        {
            var thing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeThing>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(thing.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Serialized OUTPUT:
// {"Name":"A","my_enum":"a","language_preference":"English"}
// {"Name":"B","my_enum":"b","language_preference":"English"}
// {"Name":"C","my_enum":"c","language_preference":"English"}

// Deserialize OUTPUT:
// SomeThing : a : English
// SomeThing : b : English
// SomeThing : c : English
```