# Acces the values from a json object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

The ajax call returns a json object like this:

```
Object {0: "1", 1: "jake", 2: "#00ff00", tip_id: "1", tip_details: "jake", tip_color: "#00ff00"}

Object {0: "2", 1: "jakee", 2: "#00ff00", tip_id: "2", tip_details: "jakee", tip_color: "#00ff00"}

Object {0: "3", 1: "jakeee", 2: "#00ff00", tip_id: "3", tip_details: "jakeee", tip_color: "#00ff00"}
```

This is how i try to acces some values:

```
for(var i=0;i<=response.length-1;i++){
  console.log(response[i][1]);  //the result should be: jake,jakee,jakee
}
```

I also tried:

```
for(var i=0;i<=response.length-1;i++){
      console.log(response[i].tip_details);  //the result should be: jake,jakee,jakee
}
```

I just can't get them,and i dont know why,am i missing something?

Comment: try `console.log(response)`, what is the output? Maybe it has a `data` property you need to use, I seem to remember that from something a long  time back

Comment: How are you receiving three separate objects, exactly? Let's see the code that listens for the AJAX response, if we could.

Comment: Log the `response` object like @musefan said then copy and past the output here...

Comment: If @musefan is right, then you might have to get each of the objects from `response` via `response.data[i]`, which will give you the `Object`s you listed above.

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` and then copy and paste here that will help us help u...

Comment: @ShotgunNinja , that's because i'm requesting a query from a database,and i loop through it in my js code.

Comment: 1. do `console.log(response)` 2. copy the output and paste it in your question 3. problem will be solved... it's as easy as abc

Comment: @musefan , the objects above,are outputed by console.log . There's nothing else.

Comment: Then I think we need to see the code that is making the ajax call.. Also, what server side technology are you using?

Comment: @musefan php is what i use,anyway i found the error...it was just a little syntax error...thanks everyone anyway

Answer (score 1):

That is not a JSON object. JSON notation only allows keys to be string and not numbers.

Consider taking a look at an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758715/using-number-as-index-json).

Answer (score 0):

Those are not JSON. Those are JS objects. JSON keys are ONLY String.

check what is in your `response` using `console.log(response)`. Considering that `response` is javascript array of objects, following code should return the expected output.

```
for(var i=0; i<=response.length-1; i++){
  console.log(response[i][1]);
}
```