# Why I get empty object in result?

Tags: angularjs

I have Angular JS code with filter:

```
.filter('filterSelectOptionAllowed', function () {

            var allowed = {1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4]};
            var d = {};

            return function (num, account) {
                angular.forEach(num, function (item, key) {
                    var arrElem = allowed[account];

                    if (arrElem.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                        d[key] = item;
                    }
                });

                return d;
            };
        });
```

`acount` is 3.
So, I check if `key` exists in array `arrElem` I add this element to object `d`.
Why do I get empty object `d` in return?

I tried too:

```
return function (num, account) {
                var arrElem = allowed[account];
                angular.forEach(num, function (item, key) {
                    if ($.inArray(parseInt(key), arrElem ) > -1 ){
                        d[key] = item;
                    }
                });

                return d;
            };
```

Comment: Using numbers as keys is forbidden with javascript. It screws up array referencing. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758715/using-number-as-index-json

Comment: That each statement looks logically wrong. `var arrElem = allowed[account];` will always be the same. It should either be outside the each, or corrected.

Comment: @MikeRobinson we aren't dealing with json here. numbers as indexes of objects is just fine, they get converted to strings just like everything else. `var x = {1: 'foo'}; console.log(x[1], x['1']); // 'foo', 'foo'`

Comment: I need to get object `{0: "name", 1: "name2"}`

Comment: My latest update of code is working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments key is a string so you need to type cast it for `indexOf` method with `parseInt`.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/k8gw0vst/). I'm not sure if the input data is correct because you haven't added it in your question but the filter now returns an object.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('MainController', MainController)
 .filter('filterSelectOptionAllowed', function () {

            var allowed = {1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4]};
            var d = {};

            return function (num, account) {
                console.log(num, account);
                var arrElem = allowed[account];
                
                angular.forEach(num, function (item, key) {
                    //console.log('arrel', arrElem, key, arrElem.indexOf(key), item, typeof key);
                    if (arrElem.indexOf(parseInt(key)) > -1) {
                        console.log('item', item);
                        d[key] = item;
                    }
                });

                return d;
            };
        });

function MainController($filter) {
    var elements = this.input = {0: "name", 1: "name2", 3: "name3"};
 console.log($filter('filterSelectOptionAllowed')(elements, 3));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
  input data: {{ctrl.input}}<br/>
  filtered: {{ctrl.input | filterSelectOptionAllowed: 3}}
</div>
```