# How to represent a C# Dictionary<int, string> in OpenAPI?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have a Web API which returns a object that contains a dictionary property with integer keys:

```csharp
public Dictionary<int, string> Roles { get; set; }
```

I use Swashbuckle to publish it into OpenAPI/Swagger format and this is what I get:

```json
"Roles": {
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

I am not really sure this is correct? As there is no indication that my dictionary key is an integer.

How can represent my dictionary correctly in OpenAPI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not supported because in the JSON objects/(dictionaries) the keys have to be strings.

[Another SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758715/using-number-as-index-json)