# Pluck id (integer) cast to string Laravel

Tags: php, json, forms, laravel, pluck

While plucking from a database, I get `id` as strings.

```
$alphabets = new Alphabet();
return $alphabets->pluck('name', 'id');
```

***Output***

```
{
    "1": "Apple",
    "2": "Ball",
    "3": "Cat"
}
```

***Expected***

```
{
    1: "Apple",
    2: "Ball",
    3: "Cat"
}
```

But, when I reverse `ID` and `name`,

```
return $alphabets->pluck('id', 'name');
```

I get id as integer.

```
{
    "Apple": 1,
    "Ball": 2,
    "Cat": 3
}
```

I'm not sure what's happening behind the scene. But how can I get ID in integer ? Actually, old flash session doesn't set value because of `1 vs "1"` in Form Collective.

```
{!! Form::select('alphabet', $alphabets, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => true]) !!}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer here.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pluck-id-integer-cast-to-string

**Here I found JSON only allows key names to be strings.**

[Using number as "index" (JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758715/using-number-as-index-json)

```
{
    "1": "Apple",
    "2": "Ball",
    "3": "Cat"
}
```

Actually, I want to achieve it for `Form Collective`. It was a bug and it's PR has been merged now.

https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/pull/368#pullrequestreview-46820423

Comment: How can we do it when pluck values from a pivot table where the values come always as int?

Answer (score 7):

Try this code

```
$alphabets = new Alphabet();
return $alphabets->all()->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Alphabet.php

You should cast your columns like this.

```
  protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'integer',
    'name' => 'string' 
  ];
```

Comment: To further explain this answer, when you call pluck without 'get' or 'all', it creates a 'SELECT' DB query which skips your eloquent models. However, if you call 'pluck' after 'get' or 'all', it's calling pluck on a collection of eloquent models, so these have standard Laravel casts applied to them.

Answer (score 1):

you also convert key into int

```
 $alphabets = new Alphabet();
    $alphaArr =$alphabets->pluck('name', 'id');
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
       $newArray[(int) $key] = $value;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried that too but the result is the same. Txs

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `pluck()` method gives you associative array of values 
in string values.

So, try using `select` statements like this:

```
$data = Alphabet::select('id','name')->get()->toArray();
```

This will give you following result:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Apple"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Ball"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "Cat"
  ]
]
```

Now, using simple loop you can get your expected array.

```
$expected = array();

foreach($data as $d){
    $expected[$d['name']] = $d['id'];
}

dd($expected);
```

Comment: that's the second case of my question this works but it is not expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line fix the old session issue of LaravelCollective/Html.

`|| in_array((string) $value, $selected, true)`

```
/**
 * Determine if the value is selected.
 *
 * @param  string $value
 * @param  string $selected
 *
 * @return null|string
 */
protected function getSelectedValue($value, $selected)
{
    if (is_array($selected)) {
        return in_array($value, $selected, true) || in_array((string) $value, $selected, true) ? 'selected' : null;
    } elseif ($selected instanceof Collection) {
        return $selected->contains($value) ? 'selected' : null;
    }
    return ((string) $value == (string) $selected) ? 'selected' : null;
}
```