# Laravel Form:select() Multi select options not working if array value is numeric

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravelcollective

**Form:select()**

I want to select multiple options in select, but its only work if Array index key is string, If array index key is numeric its not working...

Any help please..

**Working Example:**

```
Form::select($field_data['name'], 
         array('L' => 'Large', 'M' => 'Medium', 'S' => 'Small'), //Options list
         array('S', 'M'), //Selected values
         array('multiple')); //Multiple True
//Result: Form print and Large and Small selected
```

**Not working with Numeric Array Keys**

```
Form::select($field_data['name'], 
         array('5' => 'Large', '2' => 'Medium', '10' => 'Small'),  //Options list
         array('10', '2'),  //Selected values
         array('multiple')); //Multiple True

// Just Form>select>options print, but no option selected
```

I want to select multiple option, and options keys are numeric ids..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to integers.

```
Form::select($field_data['name'], 
         array(5 => 'Large', 2 => 'Medium', 10 => 'Small'),  //Options list
         array(10, 2),  //Selected values
         array('multiple')); //Multiple True
```

Comment: Thank you... Actually i was doing it dynamic, so i always accept string values, now i will change my code, to make it more flexible :)

Comment: @AsadRaza, welcome. Yeah, that's good practice to make everything flexible if possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can trying like this:

```
$selected = array('10', '2'); //Selected values
Form::select('sections[]',  ['5' => 'Large', '2' => 'Medium', '10' => 'Small'], $selected, ['multiple']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its actually a bug which PR has already been open.

https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/pull/368#pullrequestreview-46820423

[Pluck id (integer) cast to string Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800381/pluck-id-integer-cast-to-string-laravel/44802657#44802657)