# python json key became string not int

Tags: python, json, indexing

So I have a data in json file which i never worked before.When I load and try print the data by index like  `print(data[0])` I got and warning

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/extra/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/app/extra/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/levi/PycharmProjects/Topic-Modelling/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(data[0])
KeyError: 0
```

But When I print it like a `print(data["0"])` the result as fine as expected.So I am confused the dict indexes change to string not integer.Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem by change the keys into int.My code is like this

```
import json

def load_data(file):
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data


def write_data(file, data):
    with open(file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)


data = load_data("file.json")["teks"]
print(data["0"])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using number as "index" (JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758715/using-number-as-index-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. In JSON, object keys are always strings. The integer `0` is not a valid key. Integers are only valid for accessing JSON arrays.

Comment: so i little bit confused because of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKjjlp5_r7o&t=880s) at 8:00 he print the json by ```0``` which a int not a ```"0"``` like I did even i have the same code.Do you know a doc about that?

Comment: That is an array. If I have JSON `{"myArray": ["foo", "bar"]}` then I could access `data["myArray"][0]` in python and receive `"foo"`. However if I had JSON `{"myObject": {"property": "value", "0": "zero-keyed"}}` then of course accessing `data["myArray"][0]` would fail while `data["myArray"]["0"]` would succeed for the same reason that `data["myArray"]["property"]` would return `"value"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the conversion of keys to int as part of your read function.

```
def load_data(file):
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return {int(k): v for k, v in data.items()}
```

When writing to the json file, `json.dump()` will still write the keys as strings for it to be valid json, but after reading from the file, you will be able to access `data[0]`

If you have some keys that are strings and some that are integers, you could  try to convert to `int`, and in case an error occurs, skip the conversion.

```
def load_data(file):
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    d = dict()
    for k, v in data.items():
        try:
            d[int(k)] = v
        except ValueError:
            d[k] = v
    return d
```

Comment: I got an error ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'teks'``` and I really understand the error and the code