# RestTemplate Json annotations not working

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I'm trying to deserialize a json with the following structure

```json
{
    header: {
         type: "esummary",
         version: "0.3"
    },
    result: {
         22807455: {
              uid: "22807455",
              pubdate: "2012 Jul",
              epubdate: "",
         },
    uids: [
          "22807455"
    ]
  }
}
```

My main class PubmedResponse and the subclass PubmedResultMap is:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PubmedResponse {

    @JsonProperty("header")
    PubmedHeader header;

    @JsonProperty("result")
    PubmedResultMap resultMap;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class PubmedResultMap implements PubmedInfo{

    Map<String, PubmedResult> results;

    @JsonProperty("uids")
    List<String> uids;
}
```

However, the PubmedResultMap can't deserialize the Map starting with `22807455` and in the json I don't have a property to map to my attribute in that class. Does anyone faced that problem before.? This is the full json https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=22807455&retmode=json

Comment: json key is `result` your object property is `results`?

Comment: The json specification only allows string keys. I don't know how this was generated, but it's not a valid json.

Comment: well, `22807455` is an unknown key so it is correct that it does not get picked up. Moreover there is no `results` in `result` so how do you expect Map in PubmedResultMap to be populated

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Using number as "index" (JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758715/using-number-as-index-json).

Comment: Thanks, @Chaosfire the json is generated but another service and that is what I want to parse. I will not generate in that way, but is an external service.

Comment: @Antoniossss How can can declare that map that do not have property name.?

Comment: Literally as map. "result" is map right away, nothing to wrap